# Can I fly domestically in the USA with an expired passport?

Tags: usa, tsa

I have a passport that has expired for over a year and I just turned 18. The flight leaves in less than three weeks, so I don't think I can get a RealID or a passport renewal in time for the flight. I read online that you can use supporting documents to prove yout identity along with the expired passport. Which documents would work to support my identity or are there better methods than the passport strategy?

Comment: Do you have a non-REAL-ID driver's license or state ID? Do you have a foreign passport? green card? EAD?

Comment: It could help to know what state you're from, so you can be given advice about driver's licenses. For example, here in WA, I got my real ID in my mailbox less time than that, I think. (I was out of town so it took longer for it to be in my hands, but that's not relevant.)

Comment: I don't have a driver's license or state ID or any of the passports unfortunately. I'm from california and online it says 3-4 weeks with no expedition process which is too long for me

Comment: Is this question about the United States? If yes, it should be clearly stated somewhere. Incredible as it might be, not all people in this community live in the US.